# Definition of argv from Learning Python the Hard Way

Tags: python

I am having trouble in figuring out what's the `argv` meant in an earlier exercise of Learning Python the Hard Way (exercise 13, I've read [the post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118752/python-terminology-things-to-left-of-argv-in-learn-python-the-hard-way-exer) and still can't understand it).

Could someone explain to me what's the meaning of the 3rd line in the code

```
script, filename=argv
```

Why is there must be a "script" in the variable `argv`?

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

txt = open(filename)

print "Here's your file %r:" % filename
print txt.read()

print "Type the filename again:"
file_again = raw_input("> ")

txt_again = open(file_again)

print txt_again.read()
```

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what you don't understand from the other post, otherwise you'll just get the *exact same explanation here*.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to make it clearer as to why the other post is not sufficient to explain what is going on. Until such time, this is just a duplicate.

Comment: go to codeacademy, that's where I first picked up python (and use it for other languages still)